# multiple :contains(), only a single append()

Tags: jquery, append, contains, multiple-instances

I have a situation where I need to search multiple "li" s each for a certain different string, and if it meets the conditions in all of them, append a link to only the last one.

I am using jQuery `:contains()` to find out if each li has a certain word in it, and i can make it `.append()` to all of the li's based on the multiple conditions, but I only need it to append to the last li.

How do I get that to work? I can get it to append to all using:

```
$('li#1:contains("x"),li#2:contains("y")').append('z');
```

this gives me:

```
xz
yz
```

I need it to only give me:

```
x
yz
```

Comment: so... use the `.last()` method? or even `.eq(-1)`?

Comment: Do you have multiple `li`s with the ID of `1`?

Comment: +1 @KevinB, but also drop the `li` qualification in front of your id selectors.

Comment: I would use http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/

Comment: `$('#1:contains("x"),#2:contains("y")').last().append('z');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "next":

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var target = $('li#1:contains("x")').next('li#2:contains("y")');
    if (target){
        target.append('z');
    }
    //$('li#1:contains("x")').next('li#2:contains("y")').last().append('z');
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vuWuD/3/

EDIT: Updated to address comment.

Comment: I like this, but it's not basing it on an "and" qualification. If I take your jsfiddle and make li#1 "z", it still appends to the second one, even though it shouldn't. How do I make it work only if both conditions are met.